# Visibility.Collapsed is still showing content

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a custom control that I initially set to collapsed like so

```
<local:SpriteButton Content="Why?" x:Name="showReason" Click="showReason_Click" Margin="418,12,12,656" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

But when I run the app the Content which in this case is "Why?" shows up in there, but the whole UserControl including it's content need to be hidden.

Why is that?

The Sprite Button class looks like this

```
<Button x:Class="AppNameSpace.MyControls.SpriteButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppNameSpace.MyControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="White"
    Loaded="Button_Loaded"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave"
    ClickMode="Hover"
>

    <Button.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonCheckBoxBase" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <!--Setter Property="Padding" Value="-10"/-->
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RectButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid>
                                <local:spriteView HorizontalAlignment="Center" Sprite="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=currentSprite}" />

                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>


    <Button.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="RectButton"/>
    </Button.Style>

</Button>
```

SpriteView is yet another custom control that i am using, but that hides correct, it the contentcontrol below it which always shows up.

Comment: How is SpriteButton defined? what is in VisualState?

Comment: You're going to have to post some XAML showing the UserControl definition.

Comment: is sprite button either directly or indirectly inheriting from UIElement?

Comment: I have the same problem with UWP app [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904996/appbarbutton-visibility-is-not-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question needs more code to show what you mean......

if your trying to hide a child control or container it needs to be hidden with the parent also.

that's at least what it sounds like your asking, please post more so we can help you. :)